# DataGridView not showing contents of custom column on initial draw

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a dataGridView that binds to a list of "kit" objects as a datasource.  I have written a method `AddLocalizedStringColumn()` that adds a new

column to the datagrid ("`Localized String`"), and populates it by reading data from another column ("`stringCode`").  If the column exists already,

it just updates the values of the column.  I have placed this method inside an event based on when the datagrid's datasource changes.

The debugger confirms that all cell values are being assigned properly, including `Cell.FormattedValue`.  However, when viewing the grid for the

first time, the column is blank!  Even after running it twice during the first load, the Localized String column remains blank. If I run the

`AddLocalizedStringColumn` method a second time after the initial draw, whether by button or by event, it shows the values correctly.

I'm not sure why this is happening.  I can only imagine it has something to do with the dataGrid's initial draw.

While the actual code is proprietary, here is a similar example.

```
public static void AddLocalizedStringField(this DataGridView gridView, string localeStringIDProperty, string columnTitle, int valueIndex)
  {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(localeStringIDProperty)) return;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnTitle)) return;
            if (valueIndex < 0 || valueIndex >= gridView.Columns.Count) return;

            if (gridView.Columns.Contains(localeStringIDProperty) == false) return;

            if (gridView.Columns.Contains(columnTitle))
            {
               valueIndex = gridView.Columns.IndexOf(gridView.Columns[columnTitle]);
            }
            else
            {
                DataGridViewColumn newColumn = new DataGridViewColumn();

                newColumn.Name = columnTitle;
                newColumn.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

                gridView.Columns.Insert(valueIndex, newColumn);


            }

            int idIndex = gridView.Columns.IndexOf(gridView.Columns[localeStringIDProperty]);
            foreach(DataGridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)
            {

                DataGridViewCell foundCell = row.Cells[columnTitle];
                foundCell.Value = "English Text";
                gridView.InvalidateCell(foundCell);

            }

        }
 DataGridView dataGridViewStores = new DataGridView();
 List<Store> _listOfStores = new List<Store>();
public void SetupForm() // Runs as part of the constructor
{
    /* _listOfStores is filled with entries.*/

     dataGridViewStores.DataSource = _listOfStores;
     dataGridViewStores.AddLocalizedStringField("storeName", "translated name", 2);

     // The column appears but is blank.  The debugger shows all its cells have the correct contents.
}

public void RefreshColumn()
{
    // Running this after the form is displayed shows the localized values correctly.
    dataGridViewStores.AddLocalizedStringField("storeName", "translated name", 2);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a small, complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The code is proprietary, but I added a similar example.